# How to TRIM a pre Windows 2008 server with boot CD?

Tags: trim

I need to TRIM some NTFS disks where the OS itself is not capable.
The disks are served by a ceph cluster to KVM, where Server 2008 is running.

Why?
This server is going out of business and I will export the disks to qcow2 (sparse, skip zeros).
This only works, if empty data areas are realy empty (like SSD TRIM). This is the case for newser OSs. Discard support is enabled in KVM.

Sdelete is no solution, as it is only able to write zeros and I need to detect zeros in KVM. This also takes much more time an I/O.

Is there some kind of boot disk which is based on a new OS and has the windows defrag tool (which is TRIM capable) onboard?

Comment: [Windows To Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) comes to mind.

Comment: @gronostaj good idea, never used it but might be capable. I will try it now.

Comment: What type are the disks themselves? Do they in fact support TRIM at all?

Comment: @grawity the disks are RBD via Ceph (block storage on object storage). They are attached to Linux KVM hypervisor (VMs). Disk type is SCSI (VirtIO SCSI with discard support).

Comment: TRIM alone does not guarantee a sector will return zeros when read after being TRIMed, it depends on RZAT and DRAT support on the SSD, and even then not all SSD's support those synchronously. If you need to ensure maximum compression of the drive image, I would defrag first, disable NTFS compression and fill the remaining space with a file full of zeros, sync the filesystem, then remove the file.

Comment: @matja: Not all TRIM uses are for SSDs, and in this case it's probably already known upfront whether the RBD storage returns zeros on discard.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the disks to a Linux system with recent ntfs-3g (e.g. the Arch Linux or GParted live-CDs should work; make sure to grab the latest version). Mount them somewhere, and run `fstrim` to do the job.

```
# lsblk -f
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mnt
# fstrim -v /mnt
```

Alternatively: use `ntfsclone` to directly make a raw sparse image, then convert it to qcow2. (Ntfsclone outputs a raw image which *looks* like full-size, but unused areas will be skipped and it will be sparse at filesystem level. Qemu-img doesn't know that, but it *will* detect zeros during conversion according to the description of -S.)

```
# ntfsclone /dev/rbdsomethingorother -o server.raw
# qemu-img convert server.raw -O qcow2 server.qcow2
```